# WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing not showing product variations

Tags: woocommerce

We are selling calendars on a WooCommerce site. You can buy three variations of the product which are 'without envelopes', 'inserted into envelopes' and 'with envelopes separately'. We have different pricing depending on the quantity of calendars you buy. e.g. 1 calendar $10 each, 25 calendars $3 each, and so on.

We have set the calendar up as a variable product, created the attributes ('envelopes') and the values ('with', 'without', 'inserted'). We have also created the variations by entering their prices and making sure it's enabled.

We then go to the Dynamic Pricing tab to add a pricing group based on variation quantity, and try to select "specific variations", but no variations are listed underneath, yet they have been created in the previous tab.

If anyone could shed any light on this it would be appreciated.

Comment: which dynamic pricing plugin are you using?

Comment: @Reigel WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing. https://woocommerce.com/products/dynamic-pricing/